# memchache strict standards error on mac

Tags: php, memcached, homebrew

I am using memcahced in my project and I know memcached is install on my system. However I am getting this error

```
Strict standards: Declaration of CUSTOMMemcached::get() should be compatible with Memcached::get($key, $cache_cb = NULL, &$cas_token = NULL, &$udf_flags = NULL) in /Library/WebServer/Documents/includes/CUSTOMMemcached.inc on line 123
```

When I look at that file

I have this there

```
public function get($key, $cb = null, &$token = null){
        return parent::get($this->keyName($key), $cb, $token);
    }
```

not sure whats going on

Answer (score 0):

just compare, error says, it wants:

```
get($key, $cache_cb = NULL, &$cas_token = NULL, &$udf_flags = NULL)
```

you have:

```
get($key, $cb = null,       &$token = null)
```

try to eliminate difference

Comment: @Autolycus yes, it is, of course you should pass additional 4th argument to parent too